Filtering Entities based on the Content associated with them
I have created a custom Brand entity and designed both its Search and Details Pages. There is a relationship between M.Asset and Custom Brand. I aim to show only those Brands on Brands Landing page that have at least one associated Asset. Is there an OOTB configuration available to achieve this?
Update - I have updated my question as there was some confusion on understanding the issue

Taxonomy facet filter you can apply and filter on the basis of that.

This is not possible with the OOTB configuration as you want to filter your brands based on relation with Assets on a brand search/landing page. However, there are a couple of ways to achieve this through customization:

Add a Boolean field, 'Has Assets', to the custom brand schema. The search
component on your brand page can use this field to filter out brands
that do not have associated assets. Additionally, write an Azure
function using the web client SDK as a scheduler. This function will
execute a query and update the 'Has Assets' field based on whether
the brand is associated with any assets.

Instead of creating a brand listing page and using a filter, create a custom
React component that utilizes the JavaScript SDK. This component
will apply queries and return all brands that are associated with
assets.



Perform the following steps:

Create a Taxonomy in Sitecor Content Hub with Content-Type or Name and associate your entities with that taxonomy while creating. Refer to the documentation: Create a taxonomy
Add a new member type of Taxonomy in your Custom Entity Schema. Refer to the documentation: Create a member
Your new member type would be Taxonomy and assign the relation in the Role field. Taxonomy Member Fields
Configure Search on the Content Page Layout instead of Content Details and Optimize the filter selection using the new Taxonomy.
Refer to the blog post: How to Configure Search for the Assets Page in Sitecore Content Hub DAM

This blog post is for Assets, you can perform the same steps for Content.

You can create custom facet on the search configuration. Inside the facet type, you can select the M.Asset taxonomy item as below.

This will enable you to filter the selection based on the M.Asset value on the custom entity search page.
Hope this helps!!!
